# Aligning SwiftUI text to the baseline and top of another text

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to achieve a SwiftUI text alignment as illustrated by this image. The goal is to align the top of text ".0" with the top edge of "7" (purple line) and the bottom edge of "kts" with the bottom edge of "7" (red line).

[image: Desired result]

Here is my current SwiftUI code:

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline, spacing: 3) {
    
    Text("7")
    .font(.system(size: 70))
    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {

        Text(".7")
        .font(.system(size: 24))
        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        
        Text("kts")
        .font(.system(size: 18))
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            
    }
                
}
```

This code works for the alignment shown by the red line.

What approach would you recommend to also align the top of "7" and ".0" as shown by the purple line?

Comment: Try add `Spacer()` between the 2 views in `VStack`, also remove spacing.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use Stacks to stack font. There is no issue for the bottom line, but You can get help from the UIFont that gives you the information you need like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let bigFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 70)
    let smallFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .center)) {
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 0) {
                Text("7").font(Font(bigFont))
                Text("kts").font(Font(smallFont))
            }
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 0) {
                Text("7")
                    .font(Font(bigFont))
                    .opacity(0)
                Text(".0")
                    .font(Font(smallFont))
                    .baselineOffset((bigFont.capHeight - smallFont.capHeight))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

---

## More information:

Here is an image about the description of the `Font` for more information:

[image: Info]

Comment: Cute trick.  This kind of stuff still drives me a little nuts with SUI.  Nicely done, though.