# Keeping texts of different sizes aligned at top as the dynamic type size increases

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

I'm trying to align texts of different sizes at the top so that they stay aligned when the Dynamic Type size changes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
        Text("$")
          .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size: 24, relativeTo: .footnote))
          .baselineOffset(7)
        Text("123")
          .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size: 36, relativeTo: .footnote))
        Text("45")
          .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size: 24, relativeTo: .footnote))
          .baselineOffset(7)
      }
    }
}
```

This is aligned at top at
[Regular Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcm6v.png)

But it loses the top alignment as the Dynamic Type gets bigger: [Dynamic Type Size ExtraExtraExtraLarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA7ka.png)

Any ideas on how to keep them aligned at top even as the Dynamic Type size changes?

Comment: Have you tried setting your HStack alignment to the top and working from there? For example: HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top) { ...

Comment: @nickreps I gave it a try. Unfortunately I run into the same issue, but in the other direction - the dollar sign and cents move higher as the text size increases.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible. The problem is you are aligning the containers (`Text()`) for the text, and those containers have different padding depending on the size of the text inside. We can align baselines, but we can't align the top lines AND respond to Dynamic text. If we knew how the padding around the text was computed, then we could back it out and align the tops of the containers. It is doable if you are not responding to Dynamic Text. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63844433/7129318).

Comment: @Yrb - yes, I was looking at that answer and thought there may be a way to change the offset dynamically by setting an observer for when then Dynamic Type size changes, but couldn't figure out that path.

Comment: You could potentially work with alignment guide, for example: .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { _ in 
                                return Int //int being a dynamic value that will change based on the current dynamic type size
                            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas on how to keep them aligned at top even as the Dynamic Type size changes?

I never needed this kind of configuration but your question arose my curiosity. 
*(I keep the same context you provided: 3 Text elements with the same text styles/font and two of them having the same font size)*

- **How can I align two Text elements on top with different font sizes?** ‍
  I took a look at the font metrics to understand the returned values.

[image]
If these elements are aligned on top in a HStack view, it's the top edge that's concerned, not the letters nor the numbers inside.
So, I have to move vertically the biggest one to make its top content aligned to the smallest one.

To reach this goal, I used the [alignmentGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alignmentguide(_:computevalue:)-330fz) method that returns `a view modified with respect to its horizontal alignment according to the computation performed in the method's closure` by using the `ascender` and `capHeight` metrics difference.

- **How do I take into account the Dynamic Type feature in this implementation?** 
  The initial font sizes can be adapted to the user's preferences by using the dynamic property wrapper `@ScaledMetrics` that scales a numeric value.

I implement this information with Xcode 13.4 and iOS 15:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {

    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .footnote) var sizeMax: CGFloat=60
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .footnote) var sizeMin: CGFloat=24

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top){
                Text("$1&")
                  .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size: 24,
                                    relativeTo: .footnote))
                  .background(Color.blue)
        
                Text("a2A")
                .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size: 60,
                                  relativeTo: .footnote))
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.top){ d in
                    let customFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.init(fontAttributes: [
                            UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.family: "Helvetica",
                            UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.textStyle:"footnote"
                        ])
                
//                  Values for the font with min size.
                    let fontMin=UIFont(descriptor: customFontDescriptor,
                                       size: sizeMin)
                    let ascMin = fontMin.ascender
                    let capHeightMin = fontMin.capHeight
                
//                  Values for the font with max size.
                    let fontMax=UIFont(descriptor: customFontDescriptor,
                                       size: sizeMax)
                    let ascMax = fontMax.ascender
                    let capHeightMax = fontMax.capHeight
                
                    return abs((ascMax-capHeightMax)-(ascMin-capHeightMin))
                }
                .background(Color.gray)
        
                Text("b3B")
                  .font(Font.custom("Helvetica", size: 24,
                                    relativeTo: .footnote))
                  .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Following this rationale, I get the following result to **keep texts of different sizes aligned at top as the dynamic type size changes**. 
[image]
Don't hesitate to adapt this code snippet that fits the example you provided and that's definitely not generic.