# How to stack both to top and bottom?

Tags: swiftui

This is my code:

```
HStack {
    Text("AAA")
        .font(.system(size: 60))
    VStack {
        Text("BBB")
        Text("CCC")
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I want to align the top of 'BBB' to the top of 'AAA' and also align the bottom of 'CCC' to the bottom of 'AAA'.

I tried stack alignments, frame alignments, also tried working with custom alignments but it's all too messy and didn't work as expected.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried a Spacer() between BBB and CCC ?

Comment: The VStack height doesn't care about the height of the HStack. It could be miles long although HStack is only 50px :(

Comment: You would have to know the details of the typography of the font to do it. SwiftUI is not capable of identifying where the font begins/ends just where the `View` begins/ends. Go to a reich text editor, and pick a font with size of type 60, then scroll through the different fonts, you can see how the size of what you see is relative to the font design.

Comment: Turns out it's a huge pain to do it, but try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843516/aligning-swiftui-text-to-the-baseline-and-top-of-another-text

Answer (score 1):

Just add Spacer and fixedsize

```
    HStack {
        
        Text("AAA")
            .font(.system(size: 60))
        VStack {
            Text("BBB")
            Spacer()
            Text("CCC")
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
    }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hknjr.png)