# how to make custom font to align in center of the frame

Tags: swiftui

I need to use custom font in my app. While the built-in standard font will align in center automatically, the custom font seems to align "top"(seeing red border part) instead of "center"(blue border part). Is there any approach to fix it?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Text("SEPTEMBER")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .border(.blue)
            
            Text("SEPTEMBER")
                .font(Font.custom("Arial Hebrew", size: 20))
                .border(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to better understand your issue if you attach a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The post [Aligning SwiftUI text to the baseline and top of another text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63843516) has a useful explanation of the way a font is sized. You can get these values from a `UIFont`, so this lets you calculate an offset for centering the text.

Assuming you want the capHeight to be centered, I think the formula for the y-offset is:

> yOffset = ((lineHeight - capHeight) / 2) - (ascender - capHeight)

Applying it to your example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private func yOffset(uiFont: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        // print("lineHeight=\(uiFont.lineHeight), capHeight=\(uiFont.capHeight), ascender=\(uiFont.ascender), descender=\(uiFont.descender)")
        return ((uiFont.lineHeight - uiFont.capHeight) / 2) - (uiFont.ascender - uiFont.capHeight)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {

            Text("largeTitle")
            Text("SEPTEMBER")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .border(.blue)

            Text("Arial Hebrew, size 20 (Font)").padding(.top, 20)
            Text("SEPTEMBER")
                .font(Font.custom("Arial Hebrew", size: 20))
                .border(.red)

            if let uiFont = UIFont(name: "Arial Hebrew", size: 20) {
                Text("Arial Hebrew, size 20 (UIFont)").padding(.top, 20)
                Text("SEPTEMBER")
                    .font(Font(uiFont))
                    .border(.red)

                Text("Arial Hebrew, size 20 (UIFont, centered)").padding(.top, 20)
                Text("SEPTEMBER")
                    .font(Font(uiFont))
                    .offset(y: yOffset(uiFont: uiFont))
                    .border(.red)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: FontShift]