# How to center Text view vertically between two other views in a given container

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Problem: I am trying to vertically center a Text view between two dividers in a VStack. The issue it seems is that the frame of the Text view is offset on the top of the text and results in different spacing vertically.

I believe that the BaselineOffset ViewModifier is what I want to use, but I need help understanding how I could adjust the offset based on different font sizes. I also see that the frame of the text view itself is not center vertically between the dividers.

My current working code - this includes a rectangle for reference to check that the Vstack and dividers are giving equal vertical spacing

```
VStack {
    Divider()
    Text("Bejewled Text")
        .baselineOffset(<#T##baselineOffset: CGFloat##CGFloat#>)
        .font(.system(size: 64))
    Divider()
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .frame(width: 250, height: 100)
    Divider()
    Button("Bejewled Text") { }.font(.system(size: 64))
    Divider()
}
```

[xcode preview to show text frame within dividers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I42ck.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIFont` lets you read the dimensions of a font and you can use this information to calculate the offset. The answer to the question [Aligning SwiftUI text to the baseline and top of another text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63844433/20386264) gives a good overview of these dimensions.

Assuming you want the cap height to be centered, I think the offset is calculated as:

> ((lineHeight - capHeight) / 2) - (lineHeight - ascender)

If you try applying this with the default VStack spacing then it doesn't work very well. So I think you need to apply fixed VStack spacing, to overcome its "smart" line spacing. Then it works for the Button too:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var font: UIFont {
        UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 64)
    }

    var yOffset: CGFloat {
        let font = font
        return ((font.lineHeight - font.capHeight) / 2) - (font.lineHeight - font.ascender)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Divider()
            Text("Bejewled Text")
                .baselineOffset(yOffset)
            Divider()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 100)
            Divider()
            Button("Bejewled Text") { }
                .baselineOffset(yOffset)
            Divider()
        }
        .font(Font(font))
    }
}
```

[image: BejeweledText]

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for. I will probably try to create a ViewModifier to contain this logic for a given view - just a little polish for me